# How do you get more details about errors when running `heroku local`

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When I run `heroku local` to test my worker process, I get this:

```
forego   | starting worker.1 on port 5000
worker.1 | /myproject/source-file.js:28     # in red
worker.1 | ad (module.js:343:32)            # in red
```

The last two lines are in red, indicating an error. But the stack trace nor the error message are visible.

It's important that I do `heroku local` instead of `node source-file.js` is because I have a local environment file called `.env` whose keys are needed for the local process to consume and I'm not sure how to feed it into `node`.

How can I expand on those red messages to find out what failed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple way to do this is to use `foreman start` instead. It actually is mentioned in the [Heroku Local guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#run-your-app-locally-using-foreman). `.env` get read in the same way `heroku local` does it.